# How to create a Custom Unique Primary Key using prisma?

Tags: sql, postgresql, primary-key, prisma, primary-key-design

In my application i want to create a default primary key where the key must start with `BL-` and another rest 9 digits character must be random.

`Schema`

```
model myModel {
// try 1
id String @id @default(dbgenerated("BL-"))
// try 2
id  String @id @default(dbgenerated("BL-" + substring(uuid(), 1, 8)))

has context menu
Compose
// other fields
}
```

---

`Migrations`

```sql
-- AlterTable
ALTER TABLE "businessLoanOffers" ALTER COLUMN "id" SET DEFAULT BLO;
```

---

`ERROR`

```
Database error code: 0A000

 

Database error:
ERROR: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression

 

DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code: SqlState(E0A000), message: "cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression", detail: None, hint: None, position: None, where_: None, schema: None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None, file: Some("parse_expr.c"), line: Some(530), routine: Some("transformColumnRef") }
```

My other Possible way of solving it would be using `JS` to create the `primary-key` of my choice but i wanted to solve this issue using `prisma` and `postresql`.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, you can't use `dbgenerated()` for your use case because it's limited to what the database supports for default expressions, and custom functions or concatenations like the ones you're trying to use are not supported.

However, you can achieve your desired primary key format by using a custom function in your application code to generate the key when creating a new record.

You can use this function as a reference to create random primary key

```js
function generateCustomId(prefix = 'BL-', length = 9) {
  const characters = '0123456789';
  let result = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  }

  return prefix + result;
}
```